# ¿Es posible incluir una dll en un jar con eclipse?

Tags: java

Tengo una aplicación que utiliza un jar. Este jar depende de una dll, por lo que incluí la dll en una carpeta adentro del proyecto de eclipse. El problema es que cuando exporto el proyecto con "Runnable jar file->Package required libraries into generated JAR" solo exporta el jar sin la dll. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo correctamente?

Importante: Me gustaria distribuir la dll empaquetada en el jar. Es más que probable que los usuarios de mi aplicación no posean la dll instalada.

Comment: Sí es posible. Dependiendo con el sistema que trabajes, esto puede ser sencillo o más trabajoso. Si trabajas con maven, por ejemplo, solo basta con copiar tu dll en la carpeta resources y será parte del jar final.

Comment: ¿Y si no uso maven, ni ant, es posible?

Comment: Sí se puede, solo que no recuerdo los pasos exactos. Tengo que buscar eso.

Comment: Te recomiendo este tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html#expandablelistview tal vez va a ser para tí más sencillo y contiene el código y los layout, en base a eso puedes preguntar dudas :), saludos!

Comment: ¿Necesitas distribuir dicha DLL junto con tu proyecto o es una DLL que siempre o casi siempre estará presente en la pc de tus usuarios de la aplicación p.e. DLL propia de Windows?

Comment: De lo que estoy seguro es que mis usuarios no la tienen. Me gustaria distribuir la dll empaquetada en el jar, no por fuera.

Answer (score 1):

Dadas las características de tu escenario:

- Proyecto creado en Eclipse
- El proyecto es de tipo Java puramente, sin usar Ant, Maven, Gradle ni similares

La forma más sencilla será crear una carpeta adicional en tu proyecto, llamémosle *lib*, colocar la DLL dentro de *lib* y luego configurar *lib* para que sea una carpeta que contiene fuentes en el proyecto. Considera que cuando exportar un proyecto como JAR, lo que hará Eclipse será empaquetar todos los componentes que se encuentran en las carpetas de código fuente en el JAR. Aquí un ejemplo de fácil entendimiento.

1. En Eclipse, creamos un proyecto tipo Java llamado PruebaAgregarArchivo
2. En la raíz del proyecto, creamos la carpeta *lib*
3. En la carpeta *lib*, creamos un archivo de texto llamado datos.txt. Abre el archivo y ponle como contenido "Hola mundo!" sin comillas. Guárdalo y ciérralo.
4. En la carpeta de fuentes, creamos un paquete y dentro de él una clase que servirán para comprobar que el archivo fue empaquetado con el JAR y que se puede acceder a él desde dentro de las clases Java. En esta clase se agrega el siguiente código (nombre de paquete y de clase son irrelevantes para el ejemplo):

   ```
   //JDK mínimo: 1.7. Si utilizas una versión anterior, adapta el código
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       //se prueba el acceso al archivo datos.txt desde dentro del jar
       try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Main.class.getClassLoader().getResource("datos.txt").openStream()))) {
           System.out.println(br.readLine());
       }catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace(System.out);
       }
   }
   ```
5. Click derecho a la carpeta *lib*, selecciona Build Path / Use as Source Folder

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

6. Exporta tu proyecto Java como Runnable Jar (Jar Ejecutable). Bríndale como nombre prueba-agregar-archivo.jar
7. Ejecuta el jar desde tu consola. Deberías tener un resultado similar a este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para tu caso en particular, en lugar de utilizar un archivo *datos.txt* utilizarás tu DLL o cualquier otro recurso que necesitas en tu proyecto y que sea empaquetado junto con las fuentes en tu JAR.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes registrar nuevamente el path donde tienes tu archivo .DLL. En el menú, opción `Run` > `Run Configurations...` > `Arguments` , agrega el path que contiene tu .DLL

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Gracias buen aporte, pero me gustaría distribuir la dll dentro del jar, porque de esta forma que me indicas la ruta depende de donde hago el desarrollo. He encontrado que con "export->jar file" y activando "Export java source files and resources" si empaqueta todo, pero no encuentra el jar, ya que me manda excepcion NoClassDefFoundError en el 1er import del jar